# How can I use my ElementAt() method to access an indexed item?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I’m trying to use the ElementAt() method to access items in a loop.  In my view I have two models that I’m working with:

```
   List<SchoolIn.ViewModels.EnrolledCourseData> courses = ViewBag.Courses;        List<SchoolIn.Models.Enrollment> dayofclass = ViewBag.classDay;
```

Then in a foreach loop I have this:

```
 foreach (var course in courses.Select ((x,i)=>new{Data=x,Index=i}))
  {

     @course.Data.Title 
     if (course.Index < dayofclass.Count())
      { 

                @dayofclass.ElementAt(course.Index).classDays

      }

      if (Model.Enrollments != null)
      {

       @Html.DropDownList("searchString", Model.WeekDays.Select(s => new SelectListItem { Text = s.ToString(), Value = s.ToString() })) 
       @Html.DropDownList("searchString", Model.Enrollments.FirstOrDefault().WeekDays.Select(s => new SelectListItem { Text = s.ToString(), Value = s.ToString(), Selected = s.ToString().Equals(dayofclass.ElementAt(course.Index).classDays) })) 


      }


 }
```

This line works as expected.  It prints the string at this index of the classDays model: 
     @dayofclass.ElementAt(course.Index).classDays

What I want is to put this same string in dropdown list using the ElementAt() method.  Here’s the part of the code that throws ArgumentOutOfRange exception:

Equals(dayofclass.ElementAt(course.Index).classDays

If I hard code like this… Equals(dayofclass.ElementAt(4).classDays… it works so I’m thinking there must be some way to get at elements in my classDays.  Any ideas?

Thanks for any help with this one.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an ArgumentOutOfRangeException because the integer argument is probably longer than the size of your dayofclass list/array length.

I suppose your Index property is what it normally means. If so, you should confirm that the two lists have the same size.

Your hardcoded 4 value worked because dayofclass length is at least 5.

Answer (score 0):

Here'I solved it:

```
         String sellectedDay = dayofclass.ElementAt(course.Index).classDays; 
                   String sellectedDay = dayofclass.ElementAt(course.Index).classDays; <!---sets the element to a local variable to be used by the dropdown list--->

         selectedday = sellectedDay;
```